Generate Sitemap dynamically Nextjs + Firebase
I have a Next.js (14.2.12) app hosted on Firebase, which uses Firebase Hosting and Firebase Functions for SSR. In my app, I have blogs that I pull in dynamically from Wix. Every new post I put on Wix, is reflected on my website as a new page.
For my sitemap, I use dynamic sitemap generation.
// src/app/sitemap.js
export default async function sitemap() {
  const url = example.com/api/blogs;
  let posts = [];
  const sitemap = [
// Static pages here..
  ];
  await fetch(/*CMS blog endpoint*/)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      posts = [...data.body];
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });

  posts.forEach((post) => {
    sitemap.push({ url: `${url}/post/${post.slug}` });
  });
  return sitemap;
}

I'm using no special build configurations, just the ones that come out of the box.
The posts are added through the Wix website CRM, and then are pulled in to a private API using the Wix admin API.
This works fine, the problem is that when I add a new blog post through the CRM, the sitemap in my
/sitemap.xml doesn't have the new page for that blog post, to fix this I would have to build and deploy again, which it seems that the dyanmic fetching of the site pages in the sitemap.js seems to be only during build and not actively on request. This obviously isn't productive, so how do I automate this process?
My last case scenario would be to build and deploy as a cron job every 24h but that also isn't ideal. Is there a way to let Next.js /sitemap.xml dynamically build the sitemap on request rather than on building the project?
